# Find the device's MAC adress which is connected a static ip

Tags: macos, static, ip

We have a accounting program in our company. We can connected it via static ip when we aren't in the company. I have to find who connected the program. How can I do that? I mean how can I find the device's that connect a specific static IP.
PS: Sorry for my English :/

Comment: It *is* very unclear what you're asking...

Comment: I mean I know the static ıp how can i learn the computer's mac adresses which are connected with that ip

Comment: That very much depends on your position within the network. MAC addresses do not traverse beyond a single hop; if you're on the other side of the internet, you simply do not know. Why do you need this?

Comment: Because there's a vulnerability in our accounting program. Anyone can enter if they knows the static ip and port. Not just in our local network area. We bought the software that's way we cannot change it. But I have to ban the unauthorized access.

Comment: Well then, MAC addresses are not what you're looking for.

Comment: So what is your suggestion??

Comment: There is no simple answer without knowing a lot more about the situation. I'd generally say: put that program behind a proxy and/or firewall, and configure access on that proxy/firewall. To make it really good, require client-side SSL certificates on the proxy. Alternatively use any other authentication mechanism that suits your needs. What exactly that could be nobody can tell you, since we don't know anything about the situation. You might want to hire a consultant.